# What does a fractional frequency (for discrete-time signals) mean/how to interpret it?

Tags: sampling, frequency

This question has bugged me for a while as it's not addressed in any books I've read. I was wondering how folks from this community interpreted it. Below are my personal notes on the matter (please excuse the formal tone).

### My Notes

In the context of signal sampling, one cycle of an event represents a single, complete, sampling (measurement) of a value of a quantity. The interpretation of (positive) integer sampling rates is intuitive: fs = 5 Hz means 5 samples are taken every second. But how to do we interpret fractional sampling rates (e.g., fs = 1/3 = .333... Hz)?

By definition, a sampling frequency of 1/3 means one-third of a sample is taken every second -- but what does one-third of a sample mean? The idea of a third of a sample of a measured value is indeed absurd (is the measured value "a third-valid" and "two-thirds invalid"?) but one way to make sense of it is to consider the imperfect nature of a sampling operation.

Though we can conceive of sampling as an operation that occurs instantaneously in the abstract, we must realize that all system takes some non-zero amount of time to acquire a value of a quantity (a delay that manifests as a physical limitation of the measurement procedure or is introduced by hardware that carries out the analog sampling).

So it becomes conceivable that a unit of time (one second) might not be enough time for a single sample of a quantity to be available (or perhaps only one-third of the sample is available every second). We can interpret fractional frequency as an incomplete sample per unit time or the fraction of a sample that is available per unit time.

Another equivalent (perhaps more sensible) way to interpret a fractional sampling frequency is to interpret its mathematical inverse, the sampling period, which is the number of seconds required for a single, complete measurement of a value of a quantity.

Edit: Not sure why I was downvoted. I think this is a legitimate question. Please specify how I can improve the question.

Comment: 1/3 Hz= it takes 3 seconds for one cycle.

Comment: *By definition, a sampling frequency of 1/3 means one-third of a sample is taken every second*: **No.** That understanding is wrong: it just means that there's one sample every three seconds; since the rest of your question builds upon this false premise, I don't know what your question is. By the way, the notion of having one third of the info of one sample is contrary to your opinion not absurd – information theory and noisy communications deal with that problem *very* thoroughly.

Comment: a better question would be what does 1/\pi Hz mean?

Comment: I believe I was consistent. If 10 Hz sampling frequency meant 10 samples per sec, then one would think 1/3 Hz meant one-third of a sample per second -- or does Hz only apply to integer frequency values?

Comment: Say you're collecting water in a vial using a pump that sucks in water the rate of 1L every 3 seconds. The water sampling rate is 1/3 Hz. In the span of .3333... seconds you will have 1/3 of a Liter of water -- or 1/3 of a sample!

Comment: @MinhTran exactly this comparison is what's wrong. Samples are discrete, unlike water. You might calculate an **average** sample per time, but that doesn't *mean* anything.

Comment: @MinhTran you asked why the downvote: so you've got two interpretations in your question, one being wrong, because it is (there's no one third of a sample being taken in a second – sampling really happens every 3 seconds quasi-instantaneously), and the other one that is correct, solves all the issues, but wasn't investigated! So, you're kind of answering your own question with: "ah yes, we could interpret the sampling rate as average flow of samples, but that doesn't work out; in fact, samples are discrete, so only the interpretation as discrete events every sampling period can hold".

Comment: @MarcusMüller `one being wrong because ... there's no one third of a sample being taken in a second` Isn't this inconsistent with what you said here: `By the way, the notion of having one third of the info of one sample is contrary to your opinion not absurd – information theory and noisy communications deal with that problem very thoroughly.` I'm confused because it seems you're telling me that "a third of a sample" **doesn't mean anything** and at the same time you're telling me it means **something** in information theory.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think (and you might disagree) that the point of a "good question" (by StackExchange's standard) is one that isn't subjective, that demonstrates that the asker has thought about/tried to find the solution himself. I believe I've done that by offering my two interpretations. The crux of my question is "is there a way to interpret frequency directly and *not* in terms of its inverse, for non-integer/integral frequency values"?

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz I thought about your comment while reading about properties of discrete-time sinusoids today. _Proakis Manolakis_ in, _Digital Signal Processing: Principles, Algorithms, and Applications_, showed that discrete sinusoids whose frequency can't be expressed as a rational number aren't periodic. `x(n) = cos(2*pi*f0*n) = cos(2*pi*f0*(n+N))` if `x(n)` is periodic (with the fundamental period `N`). This is true if there exists integer `k` such that `2*pi*k = 2*pi*N*f0` or `f0 = k/N`. Because `f0 = 1/pi` is irrational, `x(n)` can't be periodic.

Comment: @MinhTran your question was about frequency. you didn’t restrict it to discrete time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better look at the sampling operation, from the **sampling period** point of view.

So a sampling frequency of $5$ Hz (which you consider as 5 **integral** samples per second) can also be understood as a uniform sampling with a sampling period of $T = 1/5 = 0.2$ seconds.
Which means that every other sample is $0.2$ second apart.

So from this pint of view, if you consider a sampling frequency of $F = 5.1$ Hz, then you would be talking about a sampling period of $T = 1/5.1 = 0.1961$ seconds, which means that every next sample will be $0.1961$ seconds away.

Since time is a continuous quantity, then you won't fall into the trap of asking whether there are integral samples or not.

Of course you can equally interpret is as you did before: you will be taking $5.1$ samples per one second. But that's counter untuitive to your integral sample concept, then be aware that it doesn't mean that there is a fractional sample rather it actually means that in one second you take $5$ net samples and spend $0.1$ sampling time empty (and wait a little more to get the next (6th) sample). So actually $5$ samples would take $5 \times 0.1961 = 0.9804$ seconds (slightly less than a second). But if you perform a sampling of 10 seconds, then you would get $51$ integral samples...

And from this last thing you would deduce that $51$ samples in $10$ seconds makes a sampling rate of $5.1$ samples per second. But no, there is no fractional sample.

Here I add a simple plot of continuous signal and its samples taken at a period of $0.35$ seconds or the sampling frequency of $1/0.35 = 2.8571$ samples per second.

[image]

In this figure, the continuous curve represents the continuous-time signal $x(t)$ and the red squares represents samples of it at a rate of $F_s = 2.8571$ samples per second, or equivalently a period of $0.35$ seconds between two samples. So when asked to compute the **rate of samples** you would use the conventional formula for (time) rate of anything:

$$ \text{rate of samples} = \frac{ \text{number of samples} -1 }  {\text{duration}} $$

As an example, compute this rate for the first $3$ samples, the duration is (from figure) $T_d = 0.7 $ seconds. And we drop the last sample from the count which yields actually $2$ samples contained in that duration. (more specifically the duration interval includes the left endpoint but discludes the right endpoint; $T_d = [0,0.7)$,  hence the sample at the right endpoint is discluded from the sample count but the duration will be same for either $T_d  = [0,7]$ or $T_d = [0,0.7)$)

So we have:

$$ \text{rate of samples} = \frac{ 3 -1 }  {0.7} = 2.8571 $$

samples per one second. Note again that according to this rate of $2.8571$ samples per second, during a 1 second interval expect about $ \lfloor 2.8571 \rfloor + 1 = 3 $ complete samples to be included. And there's some empty time left after the third sample, and that's where the illusion of a $0.8571$ fractional sample appears... of course there's no fractional sample and the next sample will be at time $t= 1.05$ seconds (outisde of the first second interval).

Comment: I think I understand your point (and perhaps Marcus') -- it's not helpful to think about frequency in terms of a "fraction of sample" because that doesn't tell us what the value for that sample is for computation.

Comment: yes quite similar...

Comment: I wouldn't quite agree, sorry! It doesn't "not tell us the value", *there is no value*; for all purposes here, the sampling *is* instant; what happens directly after one sample is taken and for the next 2.99999 s doesn't matter; what matters is the value the analog signal has **exactly** three seconds later. That's an important difference! The physical and mathematical model is that you multiply your analog signal with a Dirac delta comb, and not with something that integrates your signal between sampling instants, because otherwise, you couldn't describe aliasing.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller ! You don't agree with whom? "me" or "him" ?

Comment: @Fat32 him! (but since you said "quite similar", maybe also you, a bit)

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeah ok, but as you know sometimes it's best to leave things as they are... It seems his confusion can best be addressed this (or a similar) way. Perhaps I could make a few sketches and plot the samples to get the ultimate concrete picture, but frankly I'm a bit lazy for that now ;-) **quite similar** is the key ;-)

Comment: @Fat32 It isn't confusion so much as it is a reinterpretation of the "rules" -- in the same way that we can reinterpret Euclidean axioms to proceed with non-Euclidean geometry. I'm aware that the mathematical model for sampling, the "axiom" of this game so to speak, is to associate integer values with sampled values. I haven't thought too deeply about the implications of a "fraction of a sample" (and I certainly don't mean to suggest the idea will unravel to the depths like it did for non-euclidean geometry) but that doesn't mean _no implications_ can follow.

Comment: @MinhTran Sorry for my shallow understanding then. I though you were simply confused about fractional samples. Nevertheless, a basic signal processing text such as from Alan Oppenheim or Simon Haykin will resolve your issues I believe. In short the sample rate (frequency) is an **average** quantity and its value does not necessarily correspond to a valid entity. Just like *average number of children per family* being 2.25. So there's no 0.25 child of course. it means total of 4 families are expected to have 9 children (that's about statistical averages and distributions)

Comment: @MinhTran I added a figure...