# finding power spectral density from a vector

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, z-transform, autocorrelation, wiener-filter

I have been given a vector:
\begin{equation}
v= \:\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
my job is to find the power spectral density from this vector
\begin{equation}
\left|\Phi \:_{vv}\left(e^{jw}\right)\right|^2
\end{equation}

Can somebody please direct me in the right direction to get started on solving this problem?
I know I am supposed to use the Z transform, then evaluate the Z transform at the unit circle hence the term  \begin{equation}e^{j\omega }\end{equation}
but this is a vector and there's no dependence on a discrete time index.
Looking forward for your help. Any simple and convenient help is appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Update 1:
If,
\begin{equation}
v\left(n\right)\:\:=\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x\left(n\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x\left(n-1\right)
\end{equation}
then:
\begin{equation}
V\left(e^{j\omega }\right)\:=\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}X\left(e^{j\omega \:}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{j\omega \:\:}X\left(e^{j\omega \:\:}\right)
\end{equation}
therefore:
\begin{equation}
\frac{V\left(e^{j\omega }\right)}{X\left(e^{j\omega }\right)}\:=\:H\left(e^{j\omega }\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{j\omega \:\:\:}
\end{equation}
How to prove the response is a low pass filter response?

Comment: I assume the discrete time index is the position in the vector; meaning you have two samples in time of what is a constant signal (DC)

Comment: @DanBoschen so you mean \begin{equation} v=\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x\left(n\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x\left(n-1\right)\end{equation} is this the situation I have?

Comment: That's how I would read that.

Comment: @DanBoschen thank you. So following this, I would find a correlation matrix of v with itself. In this case, it would be a 2X2 matrix. Am I correct?

Comment: PSD is a single dimensional array: power versus frequency. Take the DFT which is a magnitude quantity, scale by N to normalize to the same units as the time axis, take the complex conjugate to convert to a power quantity and you have two bins of a "power spectral density".  The power of each bin represents the equivalent noise bandwidth of one bin (PSD is typically power/Hz but in this case you don't know the time increment so you can only do power/bin)

Comment: My task involves finding the power spectral density using correlation matrix. So basically I would somehow need to figure the correlation of that vector in the discrete time (n) domain, then convert that to the z-domain using z-tranform. Afterwards, I would have to evaluate the z-transform at the unit circle. Any insights into this path please?

Comment: Yes you are describing the DFT.

Comment: @DanBoschen  I added an update to my question, do you think am moving in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, your $H(e^{j\omega})$ looks right as the .  And you have the frequency $\omega$ mapped to the unit circle by using $e^{j\omega}$.  You probably see that "DC" or ($f=0$) is given as $z=1$, do you know where the specific frequency given by the sampling rate ($f_s$) would land?

Comment: @DanBoschen, thank you. I'm not required to do sampling. However, I do need to prove that the magnitude response would be a low pass filter. Can you please provide some insight?

Comment: Yes this is the insight— your system is already sampled. If it helps you to get a straight use time units to see that you have two samples in X seconds. What is the sampling rate and where does that map to on the “frequency axis” in the z-plane ?

Comment: @DanBoschen not sure to be honest with you. I have been stuck on this question for a really long time and very confused. the prompt doesn't mention any sampling needed.

Comment: It is not that sampling is needed but that your system is sampled (you have two samples and already worked out that it is a time index). What course is this and have you covered yet the s-plane and z-plane and how they relate? If not it may be easier for you to look carefully at the formula for the DFT and also think about how the sampling rate relates to that (the DFT is the z-transform evaluated on the unit circle ... the unit circle is the “frequency axis” on the z- plane just like the $j\omega$ axis is the frequency axis in s. Here you have two samples in time that you made into two .....

Comment: .... samples in frequency basically by using the DFT if you look at its formula carefully. So then the only remaining question is what the frequencies are that each of those points in the DFT represent. It may actually help you to understand this with a much longer time vector since that may be more intuitive

Comment: I hope I did not make that too complicated- as for the  frequency response your answer is there, you just need to plug in the values for $\omega$ as you sweep over frequency and you will see it is a low pass over a certain range

Comment: And then read this post and other ones searching on what “fractional frequency” is and specifically what it means when the frequency units are radians/sample https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/58467/21048